# mule:xml schema-validation-filter where a custom errorHandler is not being executed

Tags: java, xml, xsd, mule, xml-validation

I am using a schema-validation-filter inside a processor-chain on a flow, and i want to set a custom error-handler so that i can save the invalid lines of XML, but the problem is that my ***"schemaErrorHandler"*** is NEVER executed.

Note: My custom resource resolver, that is configured in a similar fashion as seen below, has no problems at all.

I already tried to wrap out the schema-validation-filter from the message-filter and to remove the **throwOnUnaccepted="true"** atribbute from it but the *schemaErrorHandler* is never executed.

This is a bug or I'm missing something? Neither found no JIRAs related to this .

xml

```
    <processor-chain>
        <message-filter onUnaccepted="TextValidator">
            <mxml:is-xml-filter />
        </message-filter>
        <message-filter throwOnUnaccepted="true">
            <mxml:schema-validation-filter errorHandler-ref="schemaErrorHandler" resourceResolver-ref="schemaResourceResolver" schemaLocations="mySchema.xsd"/>
        </message-filter>
    </processor-chain>

    <spring:bean id="schemaResourceResolver" name="schemaResourceResolver" class="my.app.SchemaResourceResolver"/>
    <spring:bean id="schemaErrorHandler" name="schemaErrorHandler" class="my.app.SchemaErrorHandler"/>
```

SchemaErrorHandler.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class SchemaErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

private List<Object> allErrors = new ArrayList<>();

public List<Object> getAllErrors() {
    return allErrors;
}

public void setAllErrors(List<Object> allErrors) {
    this.allErrors = allErrors;
}

@Override
public void error(SAXParseException arg0) throws SAXException {
    System.out.println(arg0.getMessage());
    allErrors.add(arg0);

}

@Override
public void fatalError(SAXParseException arg0) throws SAXException {
    System.out.println(arg0.getMessage());
    allErrors.add(arg0);
}

@Override
public void warning(SAXParseException arg0) throws SAXException {
    System.out.println(arg0.getMessage());
    allErrors.add(arg0);
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you using mxml:is-xml-filter if you are using a schema-validation-filter here ?

Comment: just to filter out and redirect non-xml messages, i could remove that but i think it  is not relevant to this question

Comment: schemaErrorHandler handles error related to schema not found or the xsd being invalid. Try removing the xsd file or having invalid content in xsd file. It will trigger the schemaErrorHandler class.

Answer (score 0):

for making the flow work you need to use a different approach. Attaching an example xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"     xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core     http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http     http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml     http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd">
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="schemaErrorHandler" name="schemaErrorHandler"
        class="SchemaErrorHandler" />
</spring:beans>

<flow name="xml_schemaFlow1" doc:name="xml_schemaFlow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="/home/anil/deleteme/xsd/file"
        responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" />



    <message-filter name="asdf" onUnaccepted="invalidRelationXmlFlow"
        doc:name="Message">
        <mulexml:schema-validation-filter
            schemaLocations="/home/anil/deleteme/xsd/xsd/abc.xsd"
            errorHandler-ref="schemaErrorHandler" returnResult="true"
            doc:name="Schema Validation">
        </mulexml:schema-validation-filter>
    </message-filter>



    <echo-component doc:name="Echo" />
</flow>

<flow name="invalidRelationXmlFlow" doc:name="invalidRelationXmlFlow">
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="hello"/>

</flow>
```

This will give you a warning in mule but does work. fine. 
In case of file validation failure the invalidRelationXmlFlow will get called.